# Handling exceptions in gRPC

Tags: java, grpc

I'm having some trouble with getting my gRPC endpoint working as expected, I've simplified my code to illustrate the issue I'm having. Essentially, I can't get the code in the `exceptionally` body to execute and I can't figure out why, it always seems to return a Status with code `UNKNOWN` but I'm expecting it to return `INVALID_ARGUMENT` as that's what I'm throwing in the `GetNamesService` class. The `System.out.println` in the exceptionally clause also doesn't print.

```
public class GrpcService extends GrpcServiceImplBase {

  private final GetNamesService getNamesService;

  public GrpcService(GetNamesService getNamesService) {
    this.getNamesService = getNamesService;
  }

  @Override
  public void getNames(NameRequest request, StreamObserver<NameResponse> responseObserver) {
    getNamesService.getNames(request)
       .thenAccept(r -> {
          responseObserver.onNext(r);
          responseObserver.onCompleted();
       })
       .exceptionally(t -> {
          System.out.println("About to handle the exception");
          responseObserver.onError(handleException(t));
       });
  }

  private StatusRuntimeException handleException(Throwable t) {
    if (t instanceof CompletionException) {
      return handleException(t.getCause());
    }

    if (t instanceof StatusRuntimeException) {
      var statusException = (StatusRuntimeException) t;
      return statusException;
    }

    return Status.UNKNOWN.withDescription(t.getMessage()).asRuntimeException();
  }
}

public class GetNamesService {

  public CompletionStage<NameResponse> getNames(NameRequest request) {
    
    // Just throwing an exception to try and get error handling to work
    throw Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        .withDescription("Invalid request")
        .asRuntimeException();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this block of fluent-style code:

```
getNamesService.getNames(request)
   .thenAccept(r -> {
      responseObserver.onNext(r);
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
   })
   .exceptionally(t -> {
      System.out.println("About to handle the exception");
      responseObserver.onError(handleException(t));
   });
```

If this entire block runs, `getNamesService.getNames(request)` is called, and the return value from that method is an object that contains a `thenAccept` method.  That method is then called, and it returns an object that contains an `exceptionally` method.  Finally, that `exceptionally` method is called.

There is no magic here.  This is just plain old Python.  This chain works because each method call returns an object that contains a method such that the next method call in the chain is valid.  If a method in the chain throws an exception instead of returning an object containing the next method in the chain, the rest of the chain isn't executed.

When `getNamesService.getNames(request)` is called and throws an exception, the remaining methods in the chain, `thenAccept` and `exceptionally`, are not executed, and so there's no reason to expect that the `System.out.println` in the block will be called.

For the code you supplied, `getNamesService.getNames(request)` always throws an exception, and so the complicated code block above is equivalent in function to just:

```
getNamesService.getNames(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mixing calling conventions. The `getNames()` returns a CompletionStage so the calling code things it is working with futures, but then it throws an exception.

If you change the implementation of `GetNamesService.getNames()` to fail the future instead of throwing, then it should resolve the issue:

```java
  public CompletionStage<NameResponse> getNames(NameRequest request) {
    // Just failing the future to try and get error handling to work
    CompletableFuture<NameResponse> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.completeExceptionally(Status.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        .withDescription("Invalid request")
        .asRuntimeException());
    return f;
  }
```

Alternatively, you can catch the exception in `GrpcService.getNames()`.